# How to resolve "Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Data.SQLite.dll’" in .net?

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, sqlite

I'm using VB.NET. I have this program develop and I successfully ran it with SQLite as its database. The problem is that, when I try to run the program in my virtual machine with Windows 7 freshly installed, it gives me an error:

> Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Data.SQLite.dll’ or one of its dependencies.

Of course, then, I included the assembly file System.Data.SQLite.dll, but still it gives me the same error. I thought this could solve the problem, I put that assembly file in the same directory inside that Windows 7. It still doesn't work.

I published my project and try to deploy it inside the Virtual Machine, but it gives me an error that System.Data.SQLite.dll should be installed inside the GAC (Global Assembly Cache). This time, I used InstallShield LE (I don't know how to use it much, I just included all the files inside the Debug Folder) and installed it inside the VM, but still the "Could not load assembly" error appears.

What should I do? What am I lacking?

Answer (score 1):

In deploying SQLite you need the underlying interop libraries. (named "Interop.Sqlite.dll")

In my deployment I use the XCOPY method mentioned on this page [SQLite XCOPY Interop](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Basically the method is to Create 2 folders inside your project, one named "x86" one "x64". Place inside each folder the 32 or 64 bit version of "Interop.SQLite.dll" and set the files properties to "Content" and "Copy If Newer" so the files are included in the output directory of the program. (the main assembly will use the correct one based on the target platform) This assumes your program is set to "Any CPU" deployment.

Otherwise you just need to include the correct "Interop.SQLite.dll" file.

This should be the basic structure of your output directory (from the link)

- bin\App.exe (YOUR PROGRAM, managed-only application executable assembly)
- bin\ ***System.Data.SQLite.dll*** (required, managed-only core assembly)
- bin\x86\ ***SQLite.Interop.dll*** (required, x86 native interop assembly)
- bin\x64\ ***SQLite.Interop.dll*** (required, x64 native interop assembly)

Answer (score 0):

When you created your installer, did you have it install SQLite to the GAC?  If not then that's not going to help.

Basically, you have two choices:

1. Have your app look for the SQLite library in the GAC, in which case SQLite must be installed on the user's machine, either manually by them or automatically by your installer.
2. Have your app look for the SQLite library in the program folder, in which case you should set the Copy Local property of the SQLite reference to True and then copy the SQLite DLL from the output folder with your EXE, either manually or via an installer.

Comment: of course I had that Copied Always... like I said, I had included the DLL already...